# Microsoft Word Tags

Tags: .net, ms-word

trying to 'Read' MS Word Document without MS Word,

i.e. trying to interpret for example something like this:

\pard\sb239\tx154\f1\fs24\b0    \uc2\u68\''44\''00\uc2\u101\''65\''00\uc2\u101\''65\''00\uc2\u114\''72\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u116\''74\''00\uc2\u105\''69\''00\uc2\u99\''63\''00\uc2\u107\''6B\''00\uc2\u115\''73\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u97\''61\''00\uc2\u114\''72\''00\uc2\u101\''65\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u98\''62\''00\uc2\u114\''72\''00\uc2\u111\''6F\''00\uc2\u119\''77\''00\uc2\u110\''6E\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u97\''61\''00\uc2\u114\''72\''00\uc2\u97\''61\''00\uc2\u99\''63\''00\uc2\u104\''68\''00\uc2\u110\''6E\''00\uc2\u105\''69\''00\uc2\u100\''64\''00\uc2\u115\''73\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u40\''28\''00\f1\fs24\i  spider family \f1\fs24\i0  \uc2\u41\''29\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u116\''74\''00\uc2\u104\''68\''00\uc2\u97\''61\''00\uc2\u116\''74\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u118\''76\''00\uc2\u97\''61\''00\uc2\u114\''72\''00\uc2\u121\''79\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u105\''69\''00\uc2\u110\''6E\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u115\''73\''00\uc2\u105\''69\''00\uc2\u122\''7A\''00\uc2\u101\''65\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u102\''66\''00\uc2\u114\''72\''00\uc2\u111\''6F\''00\uc2\u109\''6D\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u97\''61\''00\uc2\u115\''73\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u115\''73\''00\uc2\u109\''6D\''00\uc2\u97\''61\''00\uc2\u108\''6C\''00\uc2\u108\''6C\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u97\''61\''00\uc2\u115\''73\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u116\''74\''00\uc2\u104\''68\''00\uc2\u101\''65\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u104\''68\''00\uc2\u101\''65\''00\uc2\u97\''61\''00\uc2\u100\''64\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u111\''6F\''00\uc2\u102\''66\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u97\''61\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u112\''70\''00\uc2\u105\''69\''00\uc2\u110\''6E\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\uc2\u116\''74\''00\uc2\u111\''6F\''00\uc2\u32\''20\''00\par

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the File Format Documentation of the Format you want here: [File Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313105%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

But Parsing a File Format like .doc isnt the easiest thing to do, and not suitable for Beginners.